# Is there any alternate way to supply similar functions as COM does?

Tags: windows, delphi, com

Window's COM allow us to wrap our application function for out-of-process invocation.  If the COM interfaces are well defined and design, it is certainly great to consume the services via scripts and any programming platform that support COM/Automation/Active-X.

I am just wondering if there exist any alternate methods to design of what COM does?  Or something close or similar methodology?

I am using Delphi in Win32 platform.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering#Technologies

Comment: I am confused.  Why do you need an *alternative* to COM if Win32 is your platform?  Why not simply use COM?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but it seems that you're talking about an alternate to COM for creating plug-ins for your software?

If so, there are myriad options:

- TMS Software's [Plugin Framework](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tpf.asp)
- RemObject's [Hydra](http://www.remobjects.com/hydra.aspx)
- Project JEDI's [JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) includes a plugin system

You can also roll your own. I [wrote an article](http://uil.net/uArticles/ImplementingPluginsforyou.html) many years ago that provides the fundamentals (though the linked source is long since gone to the great bit bucket in the sky).

Answer (score 0):

[Corba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORBA) 
or
[IBM's SOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Object_Model)

I'm sure there are others as well but those are the 2 others i can think of off the top of my head ...

Comment: ORBs like Corba are intended for distributed multi-tier systems (roughly equivalent to DCOM) work, whereas what COM does (when used "in-process" in particular), is not that similar to an ORB. Out of process, communicating to scripts, the technical word you might be looking for is a "marshalling" solution, which both COM and DCOM provide, and which, ORBs also provide, along with other services.

A more modern-world way of doing these things might be SOAP and REST.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't say this clearly enough: CORBA and SOM are old, and were never much used on Windows.  SOM was big on OS/2. Corba got used a bit in the corporate world, but was never as big as everyone thought it would be.  ORBs were largely "killed" by the WebServices technologies, SOAP/XMLRPC/REST, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a TCP/IP (over the internet or over a LAN) interface for your objects, consider SOAP, and REST.

If you want to write plugins for your delphi app and not use COM/OLE-Automation, consider RemObjects SDK.